# update alternatives to change whole toolchain

Tags: debian, alternatives

In [debian](/questions/tagged/debian)-like distros there is a [cool tool](https://debian-administration.org/article/91/Using_the_Debian_alternatives_system) for managing multible versions of tools: It is called [update-alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). [Manual](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dpkg/update-alternatives.8.en.html).

For example, if I want to switch between two version of [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc):

```
# update-alternatives --config gcc
```

then I can choose between gcc 4.9 or 5.4 and so on ...

If I want to switch whole toolchain (gcc, g++, gfortran, ...), I have to do it tool by tool.

My question is there some cool tool to change all at once? e.g:

```
# update-alternatives --config gnu-comp-coll
```

and change every one of it? Or do I have to make script to do it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `environment module`. It is a nifty tool to change your toolchain at once.

Environment modules are basically on every Linux repo, or you can find the source code as well as the documentation on their web page.

look at

http://modules.sourceforge.net/